# Is there a way to nest one of these (Crystal Reports)

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to use these two formulas for one field.  Can someone help me combine them?

```
stringvar input := {tbl.col};
stringvar output := '';
numbervar i;

input := Trim(input);

for i := 1 to Length(input) Step 1 do 
if not(input[i] in [Chr(13),Chr(10)]) then 
   output := output + input[i];output;

if right({tbl.col},1) = "]" then
   left({tbl.col},instr({tbl.col},"[")-1)
else 
   {tbl.col};
```

Any suggestions if I want use this code first then remove white space/line breaks?
//stringvar array x := split({Police.Narrative},"]");
//numbervar i;
//numbervar j := ubound(x);
//stringvar y := "";
//for i := 1 to j-1 do(
//y := y + trim(extractstring(x[i],"","["))+"; "
//);
//if len(y) > 2 then
//left(y, len(y)-2);

Comment: Could you format it properly so that it is readable? Also, what is the input & what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a loop to remove the white space and line breaks you should be using the Replace function.